# Shading issue only while rendering

Tags: shaders, faces

I'm trying to get all the letters a gold material. In the viewport everything looks fine, but when I render it out the O gets completely black. I tried removing the subdivision modifier and bevel modifier which helped a bit, but still didn't solve my problem.

The following images showcase the problem:

[image: Viewport Blender view]

[image: Final render]

I tried recalculating normals, checked if they were flipped the right way with face orientation and unwrapped it, but all this didn't fix the issue. I'm guessing it's because of the geometry, but I'm not sure since I haven't really looked into subsurface modelling.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

If anyone wants the file to look into it, here is a link with the blend file:
https://we.tl/t-dwmWg5oaJB

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In the *OKAY Mesh* collection there is an object called *Curve.006* that is hidden in preview but that hides your *O* letter object in render, just disable its render option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe this was the problem...